# Using a wildcard with delete_transient()

Tags: cache, transient

I am using the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to hold the output for a gallery plugin's shortcode I created. Due to the number of images used and different layouts needed, the transient name looks lik the following:

```
_transient_galleries_single_shortcode_5183five
```

So - the `int` portion is the post ID it is referencing and the `five` is this specific shortcode's column setting. Where I'm running into trouble is flushing these shortcodes on-save of the referenced galleries.

What I'd normally do is something like following:

```
function galleries_delete_transient($post_id) {
    switch (get_post_type()) {
        case 'galleries':
            delete_transient('galleries_single_shortcode_'.$post_id);
        break;
    }
}
add_action('save_post','galleries_delete_transient');
```

The problem being here is that the column setting can be different based on a certain page's needs - so I was wondering if there is any type of wildcard I can use here to make this a bit more dynamic (to just clear all of them - something like `delete_transient('galleries_single_shortcode_'.$post_id%);`). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## Update

Complete shortcode function added for clarity how everything is constructed:

```
function galleries_single_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            "id"     => '',
            "columns" => 'four'
    ), $atts));

    global $galleries_options;

    $galleries_single_shortcode_output = get_transient('galleries_single_shortcode_'.$id.$columns);
    if ($galleries_single_shortcode_output === false) {

        ob_start();

        // OUTPUT HERE

        $galleries_single_shortcode_output = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        set_transient('galleries_single_shortcode_'.$id.$columns, $galleries_single_shortcode_output, 60 * 60 * 24);

    }


    return $galleries_single_shortcode_output;
}
add_shortcode('galleries_single', 'galleries_single_shortcode');
```

Comment: How do you determine the number of columns? Asked another way: how do you determine/construct the correct transient name? Knowing that method would help answer the question.

Comment: Hi @ChipBennett - added the wrapper function around the shortcode for clarity - in essence, manually added by the user `[galleries_single id=123 columns=four]`. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you saving the column setting as part of the transient key instead of as part of the data?

Comment: @s_ha_dum So if the user calls the same gallery on two different pages, but needs different column settings there won't be any conflicts and they are kept unique

Comment: I don't think the transients function accepts wildcards. It would be something like `delete_transient('galleries_single_shortcode_'.$post_id.'%%');)` if it did, though. I assume you've tested that.

Comment: Yup, tested that one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forgot I could go this route:

```
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `$wpdb->options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_galleries_%')" );
```

Comment: While this works for *you* it's important to note that this won't work for everybody. If you're using memcache (or similar), transients are not stored in the database.